# How to earn a Romanian residence permit for long distance relationship issues

Tags: residency, egypt

I have an Egyptian passport and have been in a long distance relationship for three years with a woman from Romania. I have a German residence permit expiring next year which allowed me to go see her from time to time.

What kind of visa/permit do I need to earn the right to stay at her place for as long as I can and how would I be able to live with her legally if we do decide to reside at her place? Is it only through marriage?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you searched for how to get a residence visa in Romania?

Comment: How long have you resided in Germany?  Has she lived only in Romania since you met her?

Comment: @DJClayworth Yes, but these things involved study and employment and such, I am looking for a way to stay there to end the suffering of a long distance relationship (If anyone has been through one they know how hard it is to miss their partner)
Lets say I would not mind getting an employment residence there, but it requires me to be tied with a company for three years before or something like that.

@ phoog For a year roughly, she lives in Romania and visited more countries around the world and came to visit me in Germany and Egypt.

Comment: Unfortunately the only way to get to live in a country is to get a residence visa. Essentially the only ways to do that are 1) have a job or skills that make them want to have you in the country 2) be family of a person who lives there. If you read up on how to get a residence visa that will tell you what you have to do to live there. Or your partner could end the suffering by coming to live in your country.

Comment: In addition to the visa routes listed by @DJClayworth, some countries allow applicants to obtain residence permits or even passports or by making a significant money payment or investment into the country's property or economy. This is a very small subset, but is available to some non-citizens.